# Pagination on Bounties can break

Tags: bug, new-nav

- I started out at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android
- Went to page 5
- Clicked <kbd>44 Bounties</kbd> (next to where's my tabs, in case of ambiguity)
- Was redirected to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?filter=bounties&sort=size but it displayed the "That's a miss / Empty page"
- Clicking <kbd>1</kbd> on the pagination bar shows entries as expected

It seems pagination isn't resetting when changing which questions are shown.

This isn't really a question... but I assume the bug tag is for reporting them here

Comment: Well, "is this a bug?" is a fine and dandy question ;)

Comment: That's a bug in the "new nav", which is a dead/frozen project. Better opt out of it.